# バージョンコードの変更、および、nendの広告表示について

Tags: monaca, nend

以前のフォーラムにも質問がありましたが、公式からの見解などもなくうやむやに終わっているので困っています。
cordovaの変更にともないバージョンコードが大きくなり、元に戻せない状態になりました。

現在、ハイパフォーマンス版でビルドしています。これをデフォルト版でビルドした場合は、バージョンコードが大きくならないのでUPすることができません。
なので、バージョンコードを自由に変更できれば解決するのですが、方法がわかりません。

そして、nendの広告なのですが、ハイパフォーマンス版だといつの頃からか表示されなくなりました。デフォルト版だと表示されます。

1. ハイパフォーマンス版でnendの広告が表示されなくなった理由が良くわかりません。もし、表示する方法をご存じのかたがいましたら教えてください。
2. デフォルト版なら広告が表示されるので、デフォルト版でバージョンコードを自由に設定する方法をご存じのかたがいましたら教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

ハイパフォーマンスだとCrosswalkのWebViewがかなり特殊らしくその仕様の所為で、広告を表示できないようです。Monacaサポートで詳しく聞きました。

近くドキュメントにもその旨が記載される見込みらしいです。(2015年4月3日現在)